# Sort a query result by a string column, numerically.

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a varchar column that is entirely populated by numbers.  When I execute a query with an ORDER BY clause, it sorts alphanumerically.  If I know they're all numeric but can't change the column to an integer type, how can I sort the numerically?

```
insert into table1 values(field1) ('1'), ('10'), ('2);
select * from table1 order by field1;
```

Should return:
    1, 2, 10

Comment: Note you have a syntax error : `('2);` => `('2');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the field:

```
insert into table1 values(field1) ('1'), ('10'), ('2');
select * from table1 order by cast(field1 as signed integer);
```

Comment: I don't think that ordering when inserting is even mentioned by the OP

Comment: @Cez. You're right. Overlooked a `;`. :o  removed the whining from my post.

Comment: Also the syntax is incorrect. It should read "CAST(field1 AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)" or "CAST(field1 AS SIGNED INTEGER)"

Comment: @Cez. Right again. :) I guess it's my bed time. {o